# getSupportActionBar returns null in android 4.1 and above

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, actionbarsherlock, fragment

**getSupportActionBar** returns null in android 4.1 and above. I am using support v4  and **SherlockFragmentActivity**.

**This is my logcat.**

```
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cx.android/com.cx.android.ui.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at com.cx.android.ui.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:71)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
03-10 11:35:47.876: E/Crittercism(4778):    ... 11 more
```

**This is my Edit.
This class returns NPE.**

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnNavigationListener {
    public static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

    private HomeDropdownListAdapter homeAdapter;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private DashboardFragment dashboard;

    private ActionBar actionBar;


    private static HomeActivity staticInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_main);

        staticInstance = this;
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        navStack = new Stack<Long>();

        // Action Bar
        actionBar = HomeActivity.this.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //actionBar.setDisplayOptions(10);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        homeAdapter = new HomeDropdownListAdapter(this);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(homeAdapter, this);
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(App.STARTING_NAV_INDEX);
```

**Edit 2:
Added my manifest theme:
This get called from my application tag's theme:**

```
<style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">54dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">54dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name ="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Where is your code ? Post the code of your `HomeActivity`.

Comment: What is at line 71 in Main Activity?

Comment: i have edited my question and added the code snippets please have a look

Comment: you dont need to use supportActionbar lib, its already included in android 4.0

Comment: This is my import import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

Comment: @SimplePlan This is at line 71 actionBar = HomeActivity.this.getSupportActionBar();

Comment: @GrIsHu Please look at the code n help

Comment: @sanidhyakumar also post your manifest.xml file

Comment: @SimplePlan please look at the second edit